# Encontrar termo e capturar texto imediato ou após espaço

Tags: php, regex

Tenho alguns logs de pagamentos e esses são os padrões que eles criaram o arquivo:

Padrão 1

```
Apelido
                          -- isso é um espaço
Fulano de Tal
```

Padrão 2

```
Apelido:
Fulano de Tal
```

Padrão 3

```
Apelido: Fulano de Tal
```

Como posso pegar todos os textos, que no exemplo seria o apelido "Fulano de Tal", sempre na próxima linha após o termo buscado e ignorar as linhas que tiverem espaços?

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente utilizando função preg_replace.

[ideone - resultado do seu primeiro exemplo](https://ideone.com/agu1cI)

[ideone - resultado do seu segundo exemplo](https://ideone.com/sZrxXk)

[ideone - resultado do seu terceiro exemplo](https://ideone.com/xyZ0Xt)

```
//1- retira os termos indesejados Apelido e :
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/Apelido/';
$patterns[1] = '/:/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[1] = '';
$replacements[0] = '';
$str = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);

//2- substitui quebras de linha (\n), "retornos de carro" (\r) ou tabulações (\t), por um espaço
$str = preg_replace('/[\n\r\t]/', ' ', $str);

//3- remove qualquer espaço em branco duplicado
$str = preg_replace('/\s(?=\s)/', '', $str);

//Retira espaço no ínicio e final
$str = trim($str);
```

**as expressões 2 e 3 podem ser substituídas por uma unica expressão**

`$str = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\n\r\t]/',), array(" ", " "), $str);`

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/D5FODd)

**Ou juntando 1, 2 e 3**

`$str = preg_replace(array('/Apelido/', '/:/', '/\s{2,}/', '/[\n\r\t]/',), array("",""," ", " "), $str);`

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/9iOJjX)

> A função preg_replace do php é uma função de substituição como a str_replace mas com algumas diferenças, ela suporta expressões regulares e outros recursos mais poderosos. Preg_replace pode ser utilizada para fazer substituições ou mesmo para adicionar caracteres de posições específicas em um determinado texto.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja mais simples utilizar a função `preg_match`, até porquê o objetivo é obter um trecho do texto e não substituí-lo. Código semântico.

```
if (preg_match("/(Apelido\:?)(\s+)(.*)/", $test, $matches)) {

    echo $matches[3], PHP_EOL;

}
```

Primeiro, busca-se pelo padrão `Apelido[:]`, sendo o caractere `:` opcional, armazenando este valor no grupo 1. Segundo, busca-se pelos espaços em branco, seja o próprio espaço em branco, tabulações ou quebras de linha, guardando este valor no grupo 2. Terceiro, busca-se qualquer conteúdo, guardando o valor no grupo 3. Como você necessita do valor do apelido, basta acessar o valor do grupo 3, tal como feito no `echo`.

Veja um teste:

```
$tests = [
    "Apelido\n\nFulano de Tal",
    "Apelido:\nFulano de Tal",
    "Apelido: Fulano de Tal"
];

foreach($tests as $test) {

    if (preg_match("/(Apelido\:?)(\s+)(.*)/", $test, $matches)) {

        echo $matches[3], PHP_EOL;

    }

}
```

A saída será:

```
Fulano de Tal
Fulano de Tal
Fulano de Tal
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/v1jJTO).